# Unexpected behavior when increasing network speed and connecting to a node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, express

I have a simple node.js server like:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('<!DOCTYPE html>.......');
}
app.listen(2345);
```

The html I send is 2.4kB (1.2kB when compressed).
When testing on different network speed (using dev tools) I get this unexpected behavior:

```
50kbps:  Latency 600ms, download   1ms
250kbps: Latency 300ms, download 0.6ms
750kbps: Latency 100ms, download 100ms
2Mbps:   Latency  10ms, download 200ms
32Mbps:  Latency   5ms, download 210ms
```

I don't think that the download time is supposed to increase when network speed increases after 250kbps. What is going on?
Again look at what happens if I remove compression:

```js
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('<!DOCTYPE html>.......');
}
app.listen(2345);
```

Now the file is just 2.4kB and look at the latency/download times:

```
50kbps:  Latency 550ms, download 230ms
250kbps: Latency 350ms, download  50ms
750kbps: Latency 120ms, download  15ms
2Mbps:   Latency  35ms, download   6ms
32Mbps:  Latency   4ms, download 0.5ms
```

The response with the non-gzipped content (and contet-length header) seems to be ok, but the response with the gzipped content (with transfer-encoding chunked header) doesn't seem to be ok.
What is this all about?
*I strongly encourage you to simulate a similar test yourself with whatever tools you like and see the results yourself before saying that my benchmark is wrong and that this cannot be possible. And if you get different results please share them.*

Comment: Do repeated tests have the same results?

Comment: Yep, I repeated these test so many times already and the times are all about in the same range. You can check it out yourself by doing what I did.

Comment: As I keep saying, this is not a good test.  Obviously your browser's development tools are affecting this.  Why it does that has nothing to do with your Node.js application.  Besides, your sample size and data sizes are extremely small and don't really tell you much.  If you want a real test, use a basic HTTP client and a packet sniffer.  If you want to simulate internet speeds, there are tools for doing that at the network level.

Comment: Why then if I send the same content with Apache I don't get these crazy times but completely normal behavior? As far as I can see the only difference between sending [gzipped] content with Apache and node is that one gets sent chunked and the other not chunked. And if it's the browsers fault then why when I send the same data using Apache I don't get those download times?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the compression is made on the fly and it simply takes some time -- try to compress your file beforehand and repeat your tests.

Comment: As I made the html 3.5kB the problem seems to be gone. But with 2.4kB response we get this weird behavior . Seems like too small responses behave strangely.

Comment: 50kps took a total of 601ms to download, 250kps took 300.6, 750 took 200ms., and so on. in fact, each time the network speed went up, your network time went down, just like anyone would expect. just because something buffers small gzip results before starting the download doesn't mean it defies physics...

Comment: How many simultaneous connections are you running for your tests?  What does your test harness look like?

Comment: Maybe sending the content in chunks is messing with the underlying `TCP` implementation of [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)? Just a thought. Might be worth digging further about this.

Comment: Hmm... What about to repeat your tests with 250Mb file and regular chronograph? I don't think you faced with a miracle.

Comment: 1.2kB is approx 10kb of pure payload, On a 50kpbs line how can the download time be any less than 200ms assuming? Comment from @dandavis might offer a clue.

Comment: I guess it takes ~200ms to process the uncompression, but this is done async but when there's not enough time to do it during the latency session it's added onto the download timing, likely because it's waiting for an uncompression callback before saving the timing for downloading

Comment: How are you controlling the network speeds for the tests?

Answer (score 1):

### Express.js compression options

I would also not hesitate to change the different compression quality settings, strategies and especially the treshold setting of the express compression module, as described here: https://github.com/expressjs/compression, especiall the:

#### Compression Treshold Level

Since you are sending only a few bytes of textual data as body, try to set the treshold lower then the default of **1Kb**.

> The byte threshold for the response body size before compression is considered for the response, defaults to 1kb. This is a number of bytes, any string accepted by the bytes module, or false.

*(cited from the express compression module github page)*

### HTTP Compression is not always faster

Make sure to play around with other HTTP features like HTTP Pipelining or accepted **encodings** (also on the client side) as switching those on or off may vastly alter the outcome of download time.

IBM conducted a series of excellent HTTP tests which I recommend you read about here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-httpcomp/